# Scapy/Python send HTTP GET request at packet level

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, packet

I am attempting to transmit a GET request to a server to update particular json values. I have been making use of these similar posts to do so:

[Python-Scapy or the like-How can I create an HTTP GET request at the packet level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750793/python-scapy-or-the-like-how-can-i-create-an-http-get-request-at-the-packet-leve)
[Filter HTTP Get requests packets using scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321812/filter-http-get-requests-packets-using-scapy)

How can I alter the JSON object and override the values highlight in the image that are being sent?

[image: Image of Wireshark capture]

Comment: can you give the code you have so far?